# How can I add the 'From' email address to the comments field of an activity generated by BCC email to salesforce?

Tags: email

Right now I'm trying to have multiple users prospect from within a single salesforce license, being a lot cheaper than having 1 license for each prospector.

I'm trying to separate out the users by using different acceptable email addresses within the email to salesforce settings, which then appear in the 'from' value in the comments field, alongside the current 'subject', 'To', 'CC' etc values.

How can I add this value of a sending email address as a 'From' value?

Answer (score 0):

From [Salesforce Help Guidelines on Using Email to Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_my_email_2_sfdc.htm):

If you use a company-provided or third-party email account, you can use Email to Salesforce to assign emails to leads, contacts, opportunities, and other records in Salesforce. When composing, forwarding, or replying to email, simply enter your Email to Salesforce address in the BCC field or any recipient field. Salesforce receives a copy of the email and, depending on your configuration, adds it to either the Activity History related list of the matching records or to the My Unresolved Items page, where you can manually assign it.

For more, you may also want to see [Setting Up Email to Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_my_email_2_sfdc_setup.htm&language=en_US) and [Adding Email with Email to Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_my_email_2_sfdc_using.htm&language=en_US).